# Error while trying to install R packages

Tags: r

I tried to install a package in R by typing:

```
install.packages("prob")
```

But got error:

```
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/prob_0.9-5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 707050 bytes (690 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 690 Kb

Warning in install.packages :
  write error in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'gss/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

How can I resolve it? It only happens with some packages, not all.

Comment: Hoping to be helpful and isolate your problem, i just ran `install.packages("prob")` with a positive result, no errors.  CRAN is working, my setup: R: 3.2.1. OS X: 10.10.5 Good luck,

Comment: maybe, you don't have a permission to write files into library directory?

Comment: `traceback()`? What you got after `library(gss)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is suggesting that the package requires another package `gss` that is not available. That package is not in any of the dependencies but perhaps one of the dependencies requires it in turn. `prob`'s description says:

`Version:   0.9-5
Depends:    combinat, fAsianOptions, hypergeo, VGAM`

When you look at the gss description on CRAN, it says:

`Reverse depends:   gsscopu, STAR
Reverse imports:    fBasics, timeSeq`

So I'm guessing that `fAsianOptions` requires `fBasics` and that `fBasics` needs `gss`. If I'm right, then you should try installing `gss` first, and then install `prob`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried :install.packages("gss"). But got: cannot open compressed file 'gss/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Also inside my library directory, I dont see:gss_2.1-5.zip ....even though R claims it has downloaded the package

Comment: @Victor It will be in temporary directory. R should give you message `"downloaded files are in ..."` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. My library directory was full, i needed to clear some files. Thank you for helping