# getting Error while installing DMwR package

Tags: r

hi i am getting this error message while installing DMwR package from RGUI-3.3.1.

```
Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
2: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
cannot open compressed file 'bitops/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

The error being reported is inability to open a connection. In Windows that is [often a firewall problem and is in the Windows R FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#The-Internet-download-functions-fail_002e).  The usual first attempt should be to run internet2.dll. From a console session you can use:

```
setInternet2(TRUE)
```

[NEWS for R version 3.3.1 Patched (2016-09-13 r71247)](http://r.meteo.uni.wroc.pl/doc/manuals/r-patched/NEWS.pdf) 
(Windows only) Function
setInternet2()
has no effect and will be removed in due
course.  The choice between methods
"internal"
and
"wininet"
is now made by the
method
arguments of
url()
and
download.file()
and their defaults can be set
via
options.  The out-of-the-box default remains
"wininet"
(as it has been since
R
3.2.2)

You are using version 3.3.1, this is why it is not working anymore.

**Approach 2**

The error is suggesting that the package requires another package `bitops` that is not available. That package is not in any of the dependencies but perhaps one of the dependencies requires it in turn(In this case, it is: ROCR).

Try installing:

```
install.packages("bitops",repos="https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/bitops_1.0-6.zip",dependencies=TRUE,type="source")
```

The package DMwR contains packages abind, zoo, xts, quantmod and ROCR as imports. So, additionally to installing 5 packages you must install DMwR package, Install these packages manually.

Install packages in following sequence:

```
 install.packages('abind')
 install.packages('zoo')
 install.packages('xts')
 install.packages('quantmod')
 install.packages('ROCR')
 install.packages("DMwR")
 library("DMwR")
```

**[Approach 3](http://www.crifan.com/r_language_run_code_error_could_not_find_function_geturl/):**

```
chooseCRANmirror()
```

[image]
  Select CRAN mirror from popup list. Then install packages:

```
install.packages("bitops")
install.packages("DMwR")
```

Comment: getting error like....."Error in setInternet2(TRUE) : use != NA is defunct"

Comment: Which version of installr are you using? (look at sessionInfo() )

Comment: i am geeting this..."> list.files()
 [1] "open.exe"      "R.dll"         "R.exe"         "Rblas.dll"    
 [5] "Rcmd.exe"      "Rfe.exe"       "Rgraphapp.dll" "Rgui.exe"     
 [9] "Riconv.dll"    "Rlapack.dll"   "Rscript.exe"   "RSetReg.exe"  
[13] "Rterm.exe"    
> rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
> save.image()
> list.files()
 [1] "open.exe"      "R.dll"         "R.exe"         "Rblas.dll"    
 [5] "Rcmd.exe"      "Rfe.exe"       "Rgraphapp.dll" "Rgui.exe"     
 [9] "Riconv.dll"    "Rlapack.dll"   "Rscript.exe"   "RSetReg.exe"  
[13] "Rterm.exe"

Comment: Welcome to installr version 0.17.8

Comment: > setInternet2(TRUE) 
Error in setInternet2(TRUE) : use != NA is defunct

Comment: Can you please specify, how you installing DMwR package?

Comment: still getting same error for ROCR package...above that gets succefully installed...

Comment: install.packages('ROCR')
also installing the dependencies ‘bitops’, ‘gtools’, ‘gdata’, ‘caTools’, ‘gplots’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/bitops_1.0-6.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1595 bytes
downloaded 1595 bytes

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/gtools_3.5.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 144166 bytes (140 KB)
downloaded 140 KB

Comment: trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/gdata_2.17.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1178262 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/caTools_1.17.1.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1597 bytes
downloaded 1597 bytes
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/gplots_3.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 511633 bytes (499 KB)
downloaded 499 KB

Comment: trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/ROCR_1.0-7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 152131 bytes (148 KB)
downloaded 148 KB   Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
2: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :cannot open compressed file 'bitops/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: install.packages("ROCR", dependencies=TRUE) try this

Comment: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/ROCR_1.0-7.zip' This URL displayed in error code is not working .Try to install ROCR package by providing URL manually

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROCR/index.html visit this page to get ROCR package URL. If you want zip file: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/ROCR_1.0-7.zip

Comment: > install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/ROCR_1.0-7.tar.gz",dependencies=TRUE)
ERROR: dependency 'gplots' is not available for package 'ROCR'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/library/ROCR'
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\library" "C:/Users/562542/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpacqbGj/downloaded_packages/ROCR_1.0-7.tar.gz"' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/ROCR_1.0-7.tar.gz",  :  installation of package

Comment: main culprit is bitops package.  Try to install bitops package. install.packages("bitops")

Comment: after installing bitops...restarting everything..still gettong same problem

Comment: Have you successfully installed bitops  package? you can check it using library("bitops")

Comment: ** package 'bitops' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs                but still after library("bitops") ...m getting    "Error in library("bitops") : there is no package called ‘bitops’
"

Comment: check temporary directory, see if package was installed and then move it to main directory as suggested in comment section of accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788789/error-while-trying-to-install-r-packages

Comment: When you used install.packages("bitops"), you might have seen message like this: The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpAmbFw5/downloaded_packages’ . This is temporary file location. get that downloaded file in main directory.

Comment: You can also try loading packages using : require('bitops')

Answer (score 1):

Package ‘DMwR’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
Formerly available versions can be obtained from the [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DMwR/).

https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=DMwR

You can use the function as written in CRAN package. Copy the following code in a new RScript, run it and save it for future use if you want. Once you run this function, you should be able to use the way you have been trying to use it.

```
# ===================================================
# Creating a SMOTE training sample for classification problems
#
# If called with learner=NULL (the default) is does not
# learn any model, simply returning the SMOTEd data set
#
# NOTE: It does not handle NAs!
#
# Examples:
#  ms <- SMOTE(Species ~ .,iris,'setosa',perc.under=400,perc.over=300,
#                learner='svm',gamma=0.001,cost=100)
#  newds <- SMOTE(Species ~ .,iris,'setosa',perc.under=300,k=3,perc.over=400)
#
# L. Torgo, Feb 2010
# ---------------------------------------------------
SMOTE <- function(form,data,
                  perc.over=200,k=5,
                  perc.under=200,
                  learner=NULL,...
                  )
  
  # INPUTS:
  # form a model formula
  # data the original training set (with the unbalanced distribution)
  # minCl  the minority class label
  # per.over/100 is the number of new cases (smoted cases) generated
  #              for each rare case. If perc.over < 100 a single case
  #              is generated uniquely for a randomly selected perc.over
  #              of the rare cases
  # k is the number of neighbours to consider as the pool from where
  #   the new examples are generated
  # perc.under/100 is the number of "normal" cases that are randomly
  #                selected for each smoted case
  # learner the learning system to use.
  # ...  any learning parameters to pass to learner
{

  # the column where the target variable is
  tgt <- which(names(data) == as.character(form[[2]]))
  minCl <- levels(data[,tgt])[which.min(table(data[,tgt]))]
  
  # get the cases of the minority class
  minExs <- which(data[,tgt] == minCl)

  # generate synthetic cases from these minExs
  if (tgt < ncol(data)) {
      cols <- 1:ncol(data)
      cols[c(tgt,ncol(data))] <- cols[c(ncol(data),tgt)]
      data <-  data[,cols]
  }
  newExs <- smote.exs(data[minExs,],ncol(data),perc.over,k)
  if (tgt < ncol(data)) {
      newExs <- newExs[,cols]
      data <- data[,cols]
  }
  
  # get the undersample of the "majority class" examples
  selMaj <- sample((1:NROW(data))[-minExs],
                   as.integer((perc.under/100)*nrow(newExs)),
                   replace=T)

  # the final data set (the undersample+the rare cases+the smoted exs)
  newdataset <- rbind(data[selMaj,],data[minExs,],newExs)

  # learn a model if required
  if (is.null(learner)) return(newdataset)
  else do.call(learner,list(form,newdataset,...))
}



# ===================================================
# Obtain a set of smoted examples for a set of rare cases.
# L. Torgo, Feb 2010
# ---------------------------------------------------
smote.exs <- function(data,tgt,N,k)
  # INPUTS:
  # data are the rare cases (the minority "class" cases)
  # tgt is the name of the target variable
  # N is the percentage of over-sampling to carry out;
  # and k is the number of nearest neighours to use for the generation
  # OUTPUTS:
  # The result of the function is a (N/100)*T set of generated
  # examples with rare values on the target
{
  nomatr <- c()
  T <- matrix(nrow=dim(data)[1],ncol=dim(data)[2]-1)
  for(col in seq.int(dim(T)[2]))
    if (class(data[,col]) %in% c('factor','character')) {
      T[,col] <- as.integer(data[,col])
      nomatr <- c(nomatr,col)
    } else T[,col] <- data[,col]
  
  if (N < 100) { # only a percentage of the T cases will be SMOTEd
    nT <- NROW(T)
    idx <- sample(1:nT,as.integer((N/100)*nT))
    T <- T[idx,]
    N <- 100
  }

  p <- dim(T)[2]
  nT <- dim(T)[1]

  ranges <- apply(T,2,max)-apply(T,2,min)
  
  nexs <-  as.integer(N/100) # this is the number of artificial exs generated
                                        # for each member of T
  new <- matrix(nrow=nexs*nT,ncol=p)    # the new cases

  for(i in 1:nT) {

    # the k NNs of case T[i,]
    xd <- scale(T,T[i,],ranges)
    for(a in nomatr) xd[,a] <- xd[,a]==0
    dd <- drop(xd^2 %*% rep(1, ncol(xd)))
    kNNs <- order(dd)[2:(k+1)]

    for(n in 1:nexs) {
      # select randomly one of the k NNs
      neig <- sample(1:k,1)

      ex <- vector(length=ncol(T))

      # the attribute values of the generated case
      difs <- T[kNNs[neig],]-T[i,]
      new[(i-1)*nexs+n,] <- T[i,]+runif(1)*difs
      for(a in nomatr)
        new[(i-1)*nexs+n,a] <- c(T[kNNs[neig],a],T[i,a])[1+round(runif(1),0)]

    }
  }
  newCases <- data.frame(new)
  for(a in nomatr)
    newCases[,a] <- factor(newCases[,a],levels=1:nlevels(data[,a]),labels=levels(data[,a]))

  newCases[,tgt] <- factor(rep(data[1,tgt],nrow(newCases)),levels=levels(data[,tgt]))
  colnames(newCases) <- colnames(data)
  newCases
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has been removed from the CRAN library. There are instructions on how to retrieve it from the archive.

**Either follow the link -** https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/client/#/repos/2/packages/DMwR

**OR copy-paste the three lines of code mentioned below:**

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_version('DMwR', '0.4.1')
library("DMwR")
```

EDIT: this is the error I got while downloading the DMwR package in 2022, but looks like when the question was posted, the error happened because of another reason.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. That's correct now (as stated in, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66923903/why-cant-i-install-the-dmwr-package). But in the time the OP posted, the error was because of another reason (the error message does not refer to non-availability at CRAN). it would be interesting if you just add this idea in the answer...

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing that out, I was actually looking for answers and the question headline seemed familiar to my error..

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the package '**DMwR**' was built under R version 3.4.3 
 So the solution is actually explained in the marked answer in details.
 Hence, to be short:
Just run the script below to get the problem solved!

```
install.packages('abind')
install.packages('zoo')
install.packages('xts')
install.packages('quantmod')
install.packages('ROCR')
install.packages("DMwR")

library("DMwR")
```