# Why isn't smote working when trying to create balanced data?

Tags: r

I am trying to create balanced data and used the SMOTE function.

When running my code:

```
newData <- SMOTE(number~ ., train, perc.over = 600,perc.under=100)
```

it gives me this error:

> Error in SMOTE(number~ ., train, perc.over = 600, perc.under =
>   100) :    unused arguments (perc.over = 600, perc.under = 100)

My data:

```
> head(train, 10)
     number     orderland     direction transmission       group 
1  reference Grossbritannien      RL         AUT             3
2  reference         Belgien      LL         AUT             3
3  reference  B. Deutschland      LL         AUT             3
4  reference         Belgien      LL         AUT             1
5  reference         Schweiz      LL         AUT             2
6  reference         Italien      LL         AUT             3
7  problem    B. Deutschland      LL         AUT             2
8  reference  B. Deutschland      LL         AUT             1
9  reference Grossbritannien      RL         AUT             3
10 reference         Schweiz      LL         AUT             2
```

I don't understand this error message. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I am using the **DMwR** package

Comment: It seems that the `SMOTE` function doesn't have the `perc.over` and `perc.under` params. You should really specify which package are you using and read the docs of that function.

Comment: From a really quick search there are two packages that have this function. Could it be that you are using the wrong one? Try DMwR::SMOTE ...

Comment: I first loaded the DMWr package, tried the SMOTE function which didnt work and then loaded the smotefamily package, which is also giving me an error.

Comment: For the function from the smotefamily package the error is normal as the arguments that you are specifying are not existing `SMOTE(X, target, K = 5, dup_size = 0)` is the definition I can see from the docs. The DMwR function should work though.

Comment: It works for me, have you tried by restarting the session? be sure to load the `DMwR` before calling `SMOTE`

Comment: I have restarted the session and loaded the DMWr package and ran my code and I get this error: Error in names(dn) <- dnn : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
In addition: Warning message:
In names(data) == as.character(form[[2]]) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in the other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68373410/8653046), `DMwR` has been removed from CRAN. To be able to use the `SMOTE` function from `DMwR` (and not from `smotefamily`) you will need to copy the `smote` function to an rScript and run it. Once you do this, you will be able to use the parameters `perc.under` and `perc.over`.

The `smote` function in `smotefamily` package has different parameters that you can read here about it:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smotefamily/smotefamily.pdf