# Why can't I install the DMwR package?

Tags: r

install.packages("DMwR")

> install.packages("DMwR")
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Eliomar/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> Warning in install.packages :
> package ‘DMwR’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

> 

Comment: You can also install via github using the following command: `remotes::install_github("cran/DMwR")`
Source Link: https://community.rstudio.com/t/downloading-a-package-that-has-been-removed-from-cran/107479

Answer (score 8):

See this page:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DMwR/index.html

It has been removed. There are instructions there on how to retrieve it from the archive.

If you go to the archives page and download a version you like, install it like this:

```
install.packages( "Path/To/DMwR_0.4.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source" )
```

It will likely abort and list other dependencies not met. Install those first:

```r
install.packages(c("zoo","xts","quantmod")) ## and perhaps more
```

Comment: I downloaded the file, but the response on installation was the same:

Comment: > install.packages("C:/PowerBI-DSA/Cap15/Cap15/DMwR_0.4.1.tar")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Eliomar/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘C:/PowerBI-DSA/Cap15/Cap15/DMwR_0.4.1.tar’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Comment: thats weird. Are you sure the filename is right? Try in R: `file.exists("C:/PowerBI-DSA/Cap15/Cap15/DMwR_0.4.1.tar")`

Comment: packages ususally come in a tar.gz suffix, perhaps windows explorer just hid that for you? try `install.packages("C:/PowerBI-DSA/Cap15/Cap15/DMwR_0.4.1.tar.gz")`

Comment: Works like a charm here. `install.packages("DMwR_0.4.1.tar.gz")` complains about two missing packges. `install.packages( c("xts","quantmod") )` takes care of that. after that DMwR_0.4.1.tar.gz installs just fine. Just as it should.

Comment: > file.exists("C:/PowerBI-DSA/Cap15/Cap15/DMwR_0.4.1.tar.gz")
[1] TRUE

Comment: > install.packages("C:/PowerBI-DSA/Cap15/Cap15/DMwR_0.4.1.tar.gz")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Eliomar/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘C:/PowerBI-DSA/Cap15/Cap15/DMwR_0.4.1.tar.gz’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Comment: My installation has not yet been done even adding .gz despite the R recognizing that there is a DMwR_0.4.1.tar.gz file
What can it be?

Comment: If you go by  _Tools_ -> _Install packages..._ and select package archive file, you will see it uses install.packages with the additional arguments repos=NULL and type="source". Using repos=NULL seems to be enough to make the install.packages call work. See my updated answer, you likely will have to install dependencies first, and then try again.

Comment: I used RStudio by Tools -> Install packages ... and select package archive file

Comment: > install.packages("C:/PowerBI-DSA/Cap15/Cap15/DMwR_0.4.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Eliomar/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
ERROR: dependencies 'abind', 'ROCR' are not available for package 'DMwR'
* removing 'C:/Users/Eliomar/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/DMwR'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/PowerBI-DSA/Cap15/Cap15/DMwR_0.4.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
>

Comment: And now, do I need to install abind and ROCR?

Comment: Yes, go ahead and install any packages it complains are not available

Comment: Solved. Very grateful for the precious help

Comment: install.packages(c("zoo","xts","quantmod"))
install.packages( c("xts","quantmod") )
install.packages( c("abind", "ROCR"))
install.packages("<path downloaded>/DMwR_0.4.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source" )